# Как правильно подключить Elementor Extension к WordPress теме?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

По документации разработчиков элементора я должен сделать отдельный плагин, там подключить хук `plugins_loaded`.

Мне такой подход не совсем подходит, так как я хочу сам плагин и все виджеты доставлять вместе с темой. Пробовал подключаться через init хук и через after_setup_theme - бесполезно.

В  отладчике хук самого элементора `elementor/init` не вызывается.

Comment: С чего вы решили, что хук `plugins_loaded` не сработает в теме? Сработает. Хуки `init` и `after_setup_theme` срабатывают после `plugins_loaded`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference. Раз у вас не получилось, это означает, что вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы говорите о подключении ваших кастомных виджетов в вашей теме, то этот вариант должен сработать:

```
class Your_Elementor_Widgets {

    protected static $instance = null;

    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( ! isset( static::$instance ) ) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() {
        add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [$this, 'register_widgets']);
    }

    public function register_widgets() {
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Your_Widget_Name());
        // и так далее
    }

}

add_action( 'init', function () {
    Your_Elementor_Widgets::get_instance();
} );
```

Comment: Все, сработало! спасибо большое)

Как я понял основной проблемой у меня было то что я  привязывался к хуку elementor/init, а он может сработать только во время plugins_loaded (до того как будет загружена тема).

Я почему то подумал что это "маст хэв" и по другому никак.
Оказывается из темы можно напрямую вызывать все хуки элементора. 
Спасибо еще раз)